# python is not finding module despite being listed by pip

Tags: python-import, python-module

cmd output :

PS C:\Users\Admin\Music> py area.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Music\area.py", line 1, in 
import pytesseract
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'
PS C:\Users\Admin\Music> pip list
Package     Version

---

numpy       1.24.2
packaging   23.0
Pillow      9.5.0
pip         23.0.1
pytesseract 0.3.10

i tried every python interpreter version in vs code and set up virtual enviroment and activated it

Answer (score 0):

i tried to write `pip install pytesseract` and it worked great, so it's not a naming issue. so it's most likely to be an issue with either python, pip or the OS itself.

i can't tell you if this is the issue you currently have, but seeing how you used multiple versions of pip, there's a change that you didn't chage it, and just kept on using the same version. in order to solve this, use pip3 and write `pip3 install pytesseract`.

Comment: pip3 install pytesseract gives me: Requirement already satisfied (...) for each version but im currently trying to use a virtual machine with linux to fix my problem thank you for the answer though.